# Small space between table view scroll indicator and a safe area top edge

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, safearealayoutguide

I have a scene with a UITableVIew which has a constraint between his top edge and a safe area top edge there are also left and right constraints and the bottom edge is constrained to superview bottom edge.

This configuration on UIKit 13 and 14 leads to a small 20 points space between top safe area and a table view indicator.

Do you have any solutions?

[image]
[image]